# Multiple row selection return null

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to get some of the rows of the datatable i think i wrote right code pieces but my selectedTransactions list is null. What i am missing ?

```
<p:dataTable id="financialDocumentsTable" value="#{writeoffBean.financialTransactionsList}" var="financialTransactionList" rowKey="#{financialTransactionList.txn_id}" selection="#{writeoffBean.selectedTransactions}">

<p:ajax event="page" onstart="rowsPerPageUpdate([{name:'table',value:'writeoffsForm:financialDocumentsTable'}])" />

<p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio" update="documentRevers transactionDetails" />
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px; text-align:center" exportable="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out , do not use unnecessary proces="@this" it somehow blocked the datatable and that is why my list was null.